# Convert Datagram Data To String HEX

Tags: dart

I'm Listening To UDP 6000 port and I want to convert incoming packages to Hex String

I searched but nothing found

Here is my code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:udp/udp.dart';

 main() async {
  var sender = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.loopback(port: Port(42)));

 var dataLength = await sender.send(
  "Hello World!".codeUnits, Endpoint.broadcast(port: Port(21)));

  stdout.write("${dataLength} bytes sent.");

  var receiver =
   await UDP.bind(Endpoint.unicast(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, Port(6000)));

    await receiver.listen((datagram) {
    print(datagram.data);
   }, Duration(seconds: 200));

  sender.close();
  receiver.close();
}
```

#

my incoming package is like this:

[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]

I want to Convert to this

68656c6c6f

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toRadixString` to convert to values to hex, and the map the list.

```dart
var hex = datagram.data.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16));
print(hex);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , and how to convert it to string?
without ","
now my output is :(68, 65, 6c, 6c, 6f)

Comment: You can use `hex.join();`

Comment: You may want a `padLeft(2, '0')` as well, to avoid bytes with a value below sixteen from being shown as one-digit, so `print(datagram.map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, "0")).join());`.